# how to create PWA magento 2.4 custom theme?

Tags: magento2.4, pwa, pwa-theme

I am new for PWA magento but can't understand full structure yet I have installed PWA Venia and want to create custom theme of venia like in magento we know we create a child theme and can override LUMA theme there, How can we achieve same thing in PWA?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

A good first step is to read: https://larsroettig.dev/getting-started-with-magento-pwa-studio/

It will learn you to overwrite/extend PWA Studio default components. It's not the same as we did with LUMA. Now we use [Scaffolding](https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/pwa-buildpack/scaffolding/) and the extensibility framework.

Please also have a look at: https://larsroettig.dev/getting-started-with-pwa-studio-extensibility/ for more about extensibility.

And watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fTIYrGZH0M

Using the @magento/create-pwa project initializer is the fastest way to get a PWA Studio project set up for development. It is a user-friendly version of the create-project sub-command in the pwa-buildpack CLI tool.

```
yarn create @magento/pwa
```

Or with NPM:

```
npm init @magento/pwa
```

This command launches an interactive questionnaire in the command line for configuring different parts of the project.

Also interesting to read: https://github.com/fooman/venia-ui-override-resolver

Comment: i have gone through links you provided but i am still confused like how can i override pwa core file and where should i map them to tell magneto dont use core file use mine like in magento luma we define such things in di.xml file

Comment: Exactly that is covered in: https://larsroettig.dev/getting-started-with-magento-pwa-studio/   Follow these steps to create an override on a pwa core file and it adds: <div>Static Block for TopBar</div>