# How to work with Magento PWA Studio in frontend?

Tags: pwa-studio, venia, pwa-theme

I just start to check PWA studio this week, I have read the following links and Adobe docs.
[how to create PWA magento 2.4 custom theme?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/325244/how-to-create-pwa-magento-2-4-custom-theme)

I still feel confusing here. In the Adobe docs, it shows we can create custom theme,
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/pwa-studio/guides/theming/#create-theme-files.

In this document, it shows we need to override inner components. https://onilab.com/blog/how-to-develop-a-site-using-magento-pwa-studio/

Thus, theme cannot overide the components' structure and style in pwa. is it correct ?
If I need to do some small change, for example, header style or adding new element into header, is it best practice to overide the inner component ?