# How to show default Magento Luma Theme

Tags: magento2.4, pwa-studio

I have PWA-studio with cenia theme installed. but like to switch back to the default Magento theme. how can I do this without deleting the PWA-studio and cenia theme from my server?

Comment: there is an option to set default theme in magento admin Content>>under configuration select design>> and then set your luma theme from here

Answer (score 0):

From here you can use the custom theme in the PWA:

[how to create PWA magento 2.4 custom theme?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/325244/how-to-create-pwa-magento-2-4-custom-theme)

You can use the luma theme by considering in a custom theme